# Django get sum of value from list of objects in jsonfield

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model with the following implementation

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The I have json in this format:

```json
{
  "name": "Name",
  "irrelevant_list": [],
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Name 1",
      "quantity": 1,
      "other_list_of_objects": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 2",
      "quantity": 2,
      "other_list_of_objects": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to annotate db rows with the sum of `quantity` (i.e. quantity = 3 for this db row), I have tried multiple approaches, still not getting the right query.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington postgres

Answer (score 0):

You could add a field named `quantities` CharField, and override the `clean()` method
to calculate the quantities from the instance. Don't forget to override the `save()` method to call the `full_clean()` method if you wanna keep consistency outside of django admin.
Something like this

```
def clean(self):
    sum_of_quantities = 0
    for item in self.data['items']:
        sum_of_quantities += item['quantity']
    self.quantities = sum_of_quantities
    super(MyModel, self).clean()

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_clean()
    instance = super(MyModel, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
    return instance
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am looking for the ORM related approach.